# Typescript + Angular2 test fails because of a JS library dependency

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-testing

I use jsfeat javascript library in my Angular2 project.

I put this at the beginning of my .ts and .spec.ts files:

```
declare var jsfeat: any;
```

I included jsfeat.js in my index.html.

Now I want to run Angular2 tests, but I get:

```
ReferenceError: jsfeat is not defined
```

The test code is:

```
describe('MyObj instance', function () {
  it('should instantiate MyObj', () => {
    expect(new MyObj()).toBeDefined('Whoopie!');
  });
});
```

Comment: that sounds like a runtime error, not a typescript error.

Comment: yes, it is. I can't tell the test suit to import jsfeat.js

Comment: you need to add `jsfeat` in karma.conf.js

Answer (score 0):

1) INSTALL JSFEAT WITH NPM (optional):

```
npm install -g jsfeat
```

2) EDIT karma.conf.js:

```
  config.set({
```

[...]

```
files: [
  // System.js for module loading
  'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

  // Polyfills
  'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',

  // Reflect and Zone.js
  'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
  'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',
```

[...]

Add jsfeat:

```
  'node_modules/jsfeat/build/jsfeat.js',
```